# vba unloads all userforms on unload in sub userform

Tags: vba

I have a userform that loads another userform

```
Private Sub CommandButtonAddRule_Click()
    UserFormAddRule.Show 
End Sub
```

If the `UserFormAddRule` either using "x" or a button with

```
Unload Me
```

the code return after the .show command, but then closes the first userform as well. This is what must not happen. How can I prevent the first userform to close as well?

Comment: It shouldn't be doing that.  Try it on a clean 2 user forms.

Answer (score 1):

This might have been an isolated issue, but in my case it is because the UserForm that I wanted to keep open was set to ShowModal False when it needed to be True

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim UForm As Object
Dim i As Integer
i = 0
For Each UForm In VBA.UserForms
    Debug.Print UForm.Name
    If UForm.Name <> "FormNameThatMustBeLeftOpen"
        UForm.Hide
        Unload VBA.UserForms(i)
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next
```

Hi the above has been tried, tested and should work. Your contrl structure can be an if statement, select case, or do while. The logic does not differ. if you need the same implementation using a different control structure or the full example, give me a shout.

Or you can

```
Dim i As Long
For i = VBA.UserForms.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If UForm.Name <> "FormNameThatMustBeLeftOpen"
        Unload VBA.UserForms(i)
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

**Showing and Unloading the Child with or without the VB Editor Open**

In the parent form, to create the child, and assuming the child is modal such that you cannot interact with the parent while the child is visible, which is the default, use:

dim frm as frmChild

set frm = new frmChild

... then call a public method of frmChild to initialize whatever variables it needs from the parent form in order to perform whatever task the parent is delegating to the child.

In the child form the last line of the init method should be:

me.show

Then use within the child:

me.hide

... when you are done inside the child.

Then in the parent form, immediately after calling the child's public method that initializes and shows the child, use the following line to unload the child and free memory:

set frm = nothing

The parent form will remain open.